# Determine the quantities of food that meet the nutritional requirements at least cost?

Tags: graphing-functions, linear-programming, real-numbers, problem-solving

Solve the following linear programming problem using graphical method.

A dietitian has learned from a nutritional book that his family needs at least `300` grams of protein and at least `60` milligrams iron per day for sound health. These nutrients can be obtained from meat and vegetable products. Each kilogram of meat cost an average of `₱90` and contains an average of `150` grams of protein and `15` milligrams of iron, while each kilogram of vegetables costs `₱22.50` and has `10` grams of protein and `5` milligrams of iron. He wants to determine the quantities of food that meet the nutritional requirements at least cost.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the cost equation?  What is the constraint equation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Variables**

Let
$$
\begin{split}
x &= \text{ kg of meat to buy;}\\
y &= \text{ kg of vegetable to buy.} \\
\end{split}
$$

**Constraints**

Of course the variables are non negative and, since we want at least $300$ mg of proteins and $60$ mg of iron, the constraints are

$$
\begin{split}
 150 x + 10 y &\ge 300 \\
 15 x + 5 y &\ge 60 \\
 x,y &\ge  0
\end{split}
$$

**Objective function**

We want to minimize the total cost of buying food, hence the objective function is

$$
90x + 22.50 y
$$

Therefore the problem can be rewrite as

$$
\begin{split}
&\min \ \ \, 90x + 22.50y \\
&\text{ s.t.}\quad 150x +10y \ge 300 \\
&\phantom{\text{ s.t.}} \quad 15 x + 5y \ge 60\\
&\phantom{\text{ s.t.}} \quad x,y \ge 0\\
\end{split}
$$

Can you continue from here? Which method did you use to solve this? Simplex method?

Comment: I'm lost, how do I graph it?

Comment: Try to graph the region formed by the constraints. From theory you know that an optimum is on vertex of that region.